# Как вернуть значение из функции которая была вызвана с помощью события?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, javascript-events

Эта функция вызывается по нажатию на кнопку:

```
function goToSecondLvl() {

    let number = document.getElementById('number').value;
    let url = 'http://localhost:5000/generate_code/?phone=' + number;

    function createCode(url) {
        console.log('Message create');
        fetch(url);
    }

    createCode(url);

    let firstLvl = document.getElementById('first-enter');
    firstLvl.style.display = 'none';
    secondStep();
}

document.getElementById('next').onclick = goToSecondLvl
```

;

Как я могу достать значение из функции после её выполнения и записать его в переменную?

Comment: откуда взялось secondStep()? из какой функции вы хотите получить данные?

Comment: а где тут событие?

Comment: какое значение вы хотите достать?

Comment: Хочу получить скажем number.  Second step это функция которая рисует второшай шаг. На нее можно не обращать внимание

Comment: все равно не понятно, получить куда????? где событие, при котором вызывается `goToSecondLvl`?

Comment: Та в любую переменную. Только в глобальной области видимости.

Comment: Cобытие вон внизу добавил. 
document.getElementById('next').onclick = goToSecondLvl;

Answer (score 0):

```
window.number = document.getElementById('number').value;
```